# Bellman-Ford Algorithm Short predecessor Array

Tags: bellman-ford

Having this Algorithm of Bellman-Ford with a slight change:
In line 7, instead of the inequality sign, we put `>=` so it becomes:
d[v] >= d[u] + w(u,v)

[image: Bellman-Ford]

Now I know for a fact that it will not change the distances array and it will give me a correct answer.
But how will it affect my  predecessor array on line 9? will it still give a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have non positive edges it may not be a tree, for example for the following graph and starting from n1:

[image: sample counter example graph]

In the first pass:

- by visiting e1: `d[n2] = d[n1] + w[e1] = 1` & `p[n2] = n1`
- by visiting e2: `d[n3] = d[n2] + w[e2] = 1` & `p[n3] = n2`
- by visiting e3: `d[n4] = d[n3] + w[e3] = 1` & `p[n4] = n3`
- by visiting e4: `d[n2] = d[n4] + w[e4] = 1` & `p[n2] = n4`

and in all remaining passes, this will repeat. so at the end if you iterate over predecessor for example for n2 your will get: `n2 <- n4 <- n3 <- n2 <- n4 <- ...`

But I think if you don't have non-negative edges it works fine.

Comment: Will, I remember I saw an example on the internet (I don't remember where) that shows that I will not surely get a tree from the predecessors array. Any idea?

Comment: Hmmm... seems you are right, for example if you have all edges with weight 0 and the graph is a loop, then the predecessor's array doesn't form a tree. and maybe for case with negative weighted edges something similar could happen. I should edit the answer.

Comment: Did you manage to find any example? I tried a loop with 0 weight edges, and it didnt work for me.

Comment: Check my edit, I think its an example of how it fails

Comment: Also thank you for your question, I've learned from it and it was nice to think about it :)